# How can I compare two XML files for their differences?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to compare two xml raw files and capture their differences in data. For example,

```
    <Segment>
      <SegNum>2</SegNum>
      <Dt>20110910</Dt>
      <Comment>B test</Comment>
    </Segment>
  </Retrieve>
</info>
```

File B:

```
<info>
  <Retrieve>
    <LastNameInfo>
      <LNameNum>2</LNameNum>
      <NameType/>
      <LName>TESTING</LName>
    </LastNameInfo>
    <Segment>
      <SegNum>1</SegNum>
      <Status>HS</Status>
      <Comment>A test</Comment>
    </Segment>
    <Segment>
      <SegNum>2</SegNum>
      <Dt>20110</Dt>
      <Comment>COULD I USE LINQ</Comment>
    </Segment>
  </Retrieve>
</info>
```

so the output i need should be a file with just the differences like

```
              <LNameNum>1</LnameNum> File 2:<Lnamenum>2</Lnamenum>
```

Comment: [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a library (and tool), [XML Diff and Patch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx), published to MSDN a while back that does this.

Comment: i was looking for something formatted.. which just gives the differences can u help :(

Comment: I imagine you could use the library to produce the output you need, but this would be somewhat involved, I'm guessing.

Comment: What do you mean garbage? It is unlikely you will find a library that produces the output you want directly, but the output from an XML diff can be transformed to whatever you like

Comment: i mean to say i am getting output which is not clear... I am looking for some thing like the difference in values are some graphical output.. can some one help??

Answer (score 0):

I've used the XmlDiff class in the past. At last check, it still works with framework 4.0.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302295.aspx

Comment: i was looking for something formatted.. which just gives the differences can u help :(

Comment: There used to be a online demo back when GotDotNet was still a thing. Now you'll have to roll your own application I'm afraid.